# uploading multiple files in springboot save only filename into mysql database

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Trying to upload two files into one folder at the same time I need to save those filename into mysql database with different columns.

Uploading into folder is happening but I'm not able to save those file names into database.

Comment: Post your code in order to seek help.

Comment: Show the code snippet or error stack trace?